# Storing large but predictable data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, data-structures

A program I'm writing requires a search tree with more than two million leaves. In my first implementation each leaf and node were objects that pointed to their children. The memory requirements were rather large, around half of a GB. This becomes especially problematic as each process in a multi-threaded process requires its own copy. The program in question is sometimes run on an 18-core machine, and dedicating 9GB of RAM to a search tree is unacceptable.

This data follows a rigid pattern repeated millions of times, and flexibility is not required. If this were C or C++ the clear solution would be to use a struct for each node/leaf and have single large array of that struct. I'm having trouble finding an appropriate datatype in python for this problem. Storing the data as a list of tuple or a tuple of tuples didn't alleviate the problem as much as hoped. I played around with the named tuple feature of the typing package, and it didn't seem to reduce memory requirements at all in my test cases.

My current solution is to use an integer array, with nodes pointing to their children by index in the array and with the one floating-point value converted to int by shifting the decimal point. In this particular case this was possible and dramatically reduced memory usage, but required converting data back and forth between representations and required the code to have a lot of repetition. In other use cases, though, I may need a similar structure to contain floating point data or point to other datatypes. What's the best way to do this in Python?

Comment: Have you tried the [sortedcollections](https://pypi.org/project/sortedcollections/) or [sortedcontainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) module? It is installed by default in the Anaconda distribution of Python and is easy to get otherwise. It does not have a tree--it has data structures that use less memory than a tree, since the child pointers are removed, and do most of the operations of a tree in a good time. This may or may not meet your needs.

Comment: The tree in question is a little bit more complex than key -> value pairing. The tree itself has to be written with my own custom code for the purpose. While the exact purpose of the tree is complicated to explain, the closest analogy is a KDTree, and both deal with finding points in 3D space that are close in location to the input point in 3D space.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [structclass](https://pypi.org/project/recordclass/) instead of namedtuple. Each instance of structclass is 4*8 bytes less in memory than namedtuple. The structclass does not use cyclic garbage collection and does not contain `__dict__`, which makes it possible to reduce memory usage.